# Destructuring a generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, typing

I have a function where some of the input's properties depend on the value of one of its props. So I've defined a type as follow, and it works as expected:

```
enum OrganizationPermission {
    UPDATE = 'organization:update',
    INVITE = 'organization:invite',
}

enum WorkspacePermission {
    UPDATE = 'workspace:update',
    INVITE = 'workspace:invite',
}

enum OrganizationRole {
    MANAGER = 'manager'
}

enum WorkspaceRole {
    MANAGER = 'manager'
}

type RolePermission = {
    [OrganizationPermission.UPDATE]: {
        organizationRole: OrganizationRole,
    },
    [OrganizationPermission.INVITE]: {
        organizationRole: OrganizationRole,
    },
    [WorkspacePermission.UPDATE]: {
        workspaceRole: WorkspaceRole,
    },
}

type Permissions = WorkspacePermission | OrganizationPermission;

type CheckPermissionsArgs<P extends Permissions> = {
    perform: P,
    sustain?: boolean,
} & (P extends keyof RolePermission ? RolePermission[P] : Record<string, never>);

function checkPermissions<P extends Permissions>(props: CheckPermissionsArgs<P>): void {
    // omitted for brevity
}
```

The problem arises when I have to extend this props, like in the following example:

```
type CheckRolePermissionsArgs<P extends Permissions> = CheckPermissionsArgs<P> & {
    role: string[],
}

function checkRolePermissions<P extends Permissions>({role, ...props}: CheckRolePermissionsArgs<P>): void {
    // Typing error
    checkPermissions(props);
}
```

Typescript complains that:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Pick<CheckRolePermissionsArgs
>
> , "perform" | "sustain" | Exclude<keyof (P extends OrganizationPermission | WorkspacePermission.UPDATE ? RolePermission[P] : Record<...>), "role">>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CheckPermissionsArgs<CheckRolePermissionsArgs
>
> ["perform"]>'.   Type 'Pick<CheckRolePermissionsArgs
>
> , "perform" | "sustain" | Exclude<keyof (P extends OrganizationPermission | WorkspacePermission.UPDATE ? RolePermission[P] : Record<...>), "role">>' is not assignable to type 'CheckRolePermissionsArgs
>
> ["perform"] extends OrganizationPermission | WorkspacePermission.UPDATE ? RolePermission[CheckRolePermissionsArgs<...>["perform"]] : Record<...>'

How can I refactor these typings to avoid casting the `props` argument in the second example?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because of **contravariance**, but it is only my guess. Feel free to criticize me.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) answer.

Consider next example:

```js
/**
 * VARIANCE
 */
declare var y: Omit<CheckRolePermissionsArgs<WorkspacePermission.UPDATE>, 'role'>

let x: CheckPermissionsArgs<WorkspacePermission.UPDATE> = y // ok
y = x // ok
checkPermissions(x)
```

Since, `checkRolePermissions` is higher order function:

```js
function checkRolePermissions<P extends Permissions_>(props: CheckRolePermissionsArgs<P>): void {
  // Typing error
  const { role, ...rest } = props
  type Keys = keyof typeof rest // "perform" | "sustain" | Exclude<keyof (P extends keyof RolePermission ? RolePermission[P] : Record<string, never>), "role">
  checkPermissions(rest);
}
```

TS is unable to figure out `rest` type because it is kinda dynamic type in this place. It is only known in runtime.

I think the best solution here to split `CheckPermissionsArgs` type.

```js
enum OrganizationPermission {
  UPDATE = 'organization:update',
  INVITE = 'organization:invite',

}

enum WorkspacePermission {
  UPDATE = 'workspace:update',
  INVITE = 'workspace:invite',
}


enum OrganizationRole {
  MANAGER = 'manager'
}

enum WorkspaceRole {
  MANAGER = 'manager'
}

type RolePermission = {
  [OrganizationPermission.UPDATE]: {
    organizationRole: OrganizationRole,
  },
  [OrganizationPermission.INVITE]: {
    organizationRole: OrganizationRole,
  },
  [WorkspacePermission.UPDATE]: {
    workspaceRole: WorkspaceRole,
  }
}

type Permissions_ = WorkspacePermission | OrganizationPermission;


type CheckPermissionsArgs<P extends Permissions_> = {
  perform: P,
  sustain?: boolean,
};

type Union<P extends Permissions_> = P extends keyof RolePermission ? RolePermission[P] : Record<string, never>

function checkPermissions<P extends Permissions_>(props: CheckPermissionsArgs<P>, data: Union<P>) {
  // this object has exactly the same type as you have in your question
  const merged = { ...props, ...data } 
}


type CheckRolePermissionsArgs<P extends Permissions_> = CheckPermissionsArgs<P> & {
  role: string[],
}



function checkRolePermissions<P extends Permissions_>({ role, ...rest }: CheckRolePermissionsArgs<P>) {
  // Now, TS is able to infer the type
  return (data: Union<P>) => checkPermissions(rest, data);

}


checkRolePermissions({
  perform: OrganizationPermission.UPDATE,
  sustain: true,
  role: ['sdf']
})({
  organizationRole: OrganizationRole.MANAGER,
}) // ok


checkRolePermissions({
  perform: WorkspacePermission.INVITE,
  sustain: true,
  role: ['sdf']
})({
  organizationRole: OrganizationRole.MANAGER,
}) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA8gTgcwIYgJYC8kBdUHsQAKwcEqAzmXiFAN4CwAUFFAKoEAiAggCoCiUAXigByXIhQZsVAFxgADgBNswYQBpGzAJIA5AGqa%20gkWORpMOfNNQgAbqiwr1DRgF9GjUJCgB1MQGsyOSQAY2AiEnJKfFoNVg4efiFhAHd-QJDgWUVlNVidfUMk1LgAoNCrW3tHV3dnBk9oeFNJCxAAJVwAG2AYpigAWU5tTgBxXjajYQgUJARiYRq6hp80suAO7t7mQeGxiaTpkFn5xcYsAE85Ho2w4lIKKiN6PoBtJolzKnD7qJAAOjYXD4AF1pFtmFATB8pPgbmD3mYYe0usAnMwXGioG9xIjWt9IlQ-vkDLxQeDmFDcVQ4bAcS1qSjMRjYi9fCV0qF8Q98AD4iCwc8IVBiqUMjS2aLQjcmacGBcrlAub8yAB9IwSjm3CLc6gAH1pzU%20%20CVVAA3LUzpcegBhAAWwGCfhN%20DInEQZAAPAQoMAAB4OEAKMiKu4El0qgB8T1iVzgADMxBAwQRMWQwGQsEhrAB%20MEAI1wKJQThc5rq8p6LDQ%20C9Pv9oCDIe1ysjRm9foDjb8wHOuDjUBuzuo2YHKKHLwIwKgYLaDrECg9Gbg1gQqigIGANmIEdqcbAIGCrSgwXtjqHnvb9cDwfPkYAFHI4Lg5GQwXaHU7QzrXe6vRG10omZglWVB-gAlOCwQulgUAQMQcwKE8UB-Chj7PmQa4oX8gFIFALhQAA9ARUC2rKloKu%20jqDl%20ypuggF51p2N40VQqpRkIlGfs2rF0ReUYAGTgk%203RgkuK4vMCJYWnUe4HkeJ4ftR3EurWHYNsxykgGxd40FAwmoshKFwMAGZ4W%20p5%20EpPw8b%20BARhBgqEcR3CXCuPpwE%20cCxMZWBgHA1B3jhwHViA4GCFGClnixLp3sZGYAdgSBgWWZEMJFlljtFWk6TGxAJiQ8J0kahBZbyQK8Km6aZtYYJYHAYCot5KJgi8whkAocbCMCrhgTlfSUvSsLNQa0KtDcfw7KM4wlhBRGQn40npVZYbZY5sb5UmKzsmsQ5EnoJKVRmWYgLV9WNX0%20ktW1HVdT1fUUkVSI0gig3It0E1DFNbQzU5dZXIewCIcQnm1EAA)

Comment: I don't have this option. I just simplified for brevity, but the real case involves a react component, so I can't have a second parameter as suggested.